# How to draw image data on window client area using win32 c++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am working on Visual Studio 12 (Windows 10 OS) and trying to display an image buffer using `StretchDIBits()`, but it's failing with return 0.

I don't have any header file for that buffer. I don't know how to draw the client area using only buffer data. If anyone knows, please share your thoughts.

I have added sample snippet below:

```
void DShow::set framebuffer(HDC hDC){
    BITMAPINFO m_bi;
    DWORD result = 0;

    m_bi.bmiHeader.biSize   =     sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biWidth  =     m_curResolutionWidth;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biHeight =     m_curResolutionHeight;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes =     (WORD)1;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount =    (WORD)24;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage =  (m_curResolutionWidth*m_curResolutionHeight)*(24/8);
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    m_bi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    result = StretchDIBits(hDC,
                         m_TaniaDestRect.left, m_TaniaDestRect.top,
                         m_TaniaDestRect.right - m_TaniaDestRect.left, m_TaniaDestRect.bottom - m_TaniaDestRect.top,
                         0, 0,
                         m_curResolutionWidth, abs(m_curResolutionHeight),
                         g_pBuffer, &m_bi,
                         DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Comment: You are calculating `biSizeImage` incorrectly. The size of a scanline in bytes must be aligned to the next DWORD boundary (i. e. a multiple of 4). Set `biSizeImage` to zero (a valid value) or use a correct formula.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for updating but I tried that still showing the black screen.

Comment: Have you checked that the image buffer actually contains something other than all zeros? What is the return value of `StretchDIBits`?

Comment: yes, I  checked it not contained zeros.